# file_exists in php code

Tags: php, file-exists

I have a simple statement below:

```
if(file_exists('/images/alum/'.$profile['pic'])) 
  echo '/images/alum/'.$profile['pic']; 
  else echo '/images/user_default.jpg';
```

The file is there but it's always going to the default image. What have I got wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your path is correct? Try `./images/alum/`...

Comment: I would advise to do some reading about relative and absolute paths - both file paths (path of file that resides on filesystem) and URL paths (address that is being used with `<a href=''></a>` and other HTML tags). After reading about it, you should understand and be able to tell when (and why) to use `./images/`, `images/` or `/images/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying on the server that the file at the root of the file system exists. You will have to probably add some `.` or `..`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(file_exists('./images/alum/'.$profile['pic']))
 echo '/images/alum/'.$profile['pic']; 
 else echo '/images/user_default.jpg';
```

i.e. changing the "/images" to "./images" but only in the file_exists call.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this.

```
if(file_exists('./images/alum/'.$profile['pic'])) 
    echo './images/alum/'.$profile['pic']; 
else 
    echo './images/user_default.jpg';
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that `$profile['pic']` has valid file name, contraction with path is valid, and current directory with parth point to file...

temporary negate condition to see file from profile...